# How to get a snapshot of Angular's components state?

Tags: angular

I have this concept of an estimate application(build with angular-cli) where the user can have dynamic number of child components and I need to store the components state/data for future edits/exports.

Answer (score 0):

Angular has provided the concept of `service` to store the component's state for further use. Every service instance is a singleton object.

**Way to write Service in Angular 2**

MyService.ts

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';

@injectable()
export class MyService {
  compState: string;

  getCompState() {
    return this.compState;
  }

  setCompState(state) {
    this.compState = state;
  }
}
```

**Way to register it with Angular Module**

app.module.ts

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {MyService} from './MyService';

@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [...],
  providers: [MyService]
})

export AppModule {}
```

**Way to use it**

MyComp.ts

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {MyService} from './MyService';

@Component({})

export MyComp {
  constructor(private myService: MyService) {

  }
}
```

Comment: You are suggesting to store any component property in a service injected at module level (singleton), right?  I was trying to find something more elegant than a Map of Maps.